# $17\mid19^{8n}-1\;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, congruences

Show that $17\mid19^{8n}-1\;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.
I thought about using arithmetic of the remains, proving that $1\equiv19^{8n}\pmod{17}$ And I could not do it: (

Comment: @barto I know this theorem, tried using induction, but found very complicated, and my view of to do for modular arithmetic, but I'm still studying this content, started a few days, and still do not understand well.

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

$$19\equiv2\pmod{17}\;,\;\;2^4\equiv-1\pmod{17}\implies$$

$$19^{8n}-1\equiv\left(2^4\right)^{2n}-1\pmod{17}\equiv\ldots$$

Comment: Hints:

$$19\equiv2\pmod{17}\;,\;\;2^4\equiv-1\pmod{17}\implies$$

$$19^{8n}-1\equiv\left(2^4\right)^{2n}-1\pmod{17}\equiv 16^{2n}-1\pmod{17}\equiv2^{8n}-1\pmod{17}?$$ and?

Comment: ...and $$(2^4)^{2n}=(-1)^{2n}=1\ldots$$